# Angular2, nest component in different directory

Tags: angular

I have a component in a different directory that I would like to nest as a child in a different component

`./folder1/view/view.component.ts` and `./folder2/test/test.component.ts`

I want to do this:

```
<app-test>
  <app-view></app-view>
</app-test>
```

I've placed in the `app.module` but that didn't do it.

Comment: Have you add `<ng-content></ng-content>` in your `app-test` template?

Comment: What error are you getting?